# bulk insert elasticsearch documents except one field if the document already exists

Tags: bulkinsert, elasticsearch

I need to bulk insert if not existing, but I need override the whole document except one field if the document already exists.

for example:

if the database contains this document

```
{
  "_id": 234,
  "text": "hello",
  "reach": 20
}
```

when i update using this document

```
{
  "_id": 234,
  "text": "hawdy",
  "reach": 24
 }
```

the document in the data post should contain

```
{
  "_id": 234,
  "text": "hawdy",
  "reach": 20
 }
```

if the document didn't exist in the database The second document should be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [upsert option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#upserts) of [bulk update](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#bulk-update) API for this.